# Как сделать выбор option в select в зависимости от даты в input на JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Нуждаюсь в помощи профи!
Есть поле с выбором статуса:

```
<select id="opta">
<option id="now">Now</option>
<option id="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

И есть поле input:

```
<input type="text" name="xfdate" placeholder="дд.мм.гггг" id="xfdate" value="" rel="essential">
```

К полю input привязан календарь(выбирается дата и она вписывается) DatePicker.js

Помогите пожалуйста сделать js скрипт который бы автоматически выбирал статус в зависимости от указанной даты в input. 
Если указана будущая дата(от настоящего времени) то в select выбирается автоматически "other"
Ну а если указана текущая дата или прошлая то автоматом выбирается now

Слаб в js. В интернете ничего похожего не нашел, посоветовали написать тут. 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так?

```js
selectValue("xfdate1", "other1");
selectValue("xfdate2", "other2");

function selectValue(inputId, optionId) {
  let date = document.getElementById(inputId).value.split('.').reverse().join('-');
  if (0 > new Date().getTime() - new Date(date).getTime()) 
    document.getElementById(optionId).selected = true;
}
```

```html
<select id="opta1">
  <option id="now1">Now</option>
  <option id="other1">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="xfdate" placeholder="дд.мм.гггг" id="xfdate1" value="29.01.1999" rel="essential">
<br>
<select id="opta2">
  <option id="now2">Now</option>
  <option id="other2">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="xfdate" placeholder="дд.мм.гггг" id="xfdate2" value="29.01.2222" rel="essential">
```